# setting soket.io transports client-side

Tags: websocket, socket.io, socket.io-1.0

In socket.io v0.9 I could set the available transports in my javascript client (in the browser) like so:

```
io.transports = ["xhr-polling", "jsonp-polling"]
```

How would I do the same thing in socket.io 1.0?

Answer (score 0):

Here's what worked:

```
socket = io.connect("http://www.example.com", {
  transports: ['polling']
})
```